# Rake Preview displays my octropress blog as a blank page on localhost:4000

Tags: rake, octopress, github-pages

I have written my first post on octopress using:

```
rake new_post 'name_of_post'
```

I can see my post inside _source/_posts/'2014-01......

When I try to run the command

```
rake preview
```

this is what the terminal outputs:

```
source$ rake preview
(in /Users/steclaudinodaffara/Documents/blog/cdSte/octopress)
Starting to watch source with Jekyll and Compass. Starting Rack on port 4000
Configuration from /Users/steclaudinodaffara/Documents/blog/cdSte/octopress/_config.yml
[2014-01-16 09:26:55] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-01-16 09:26:55] INFO  ruby 2.1.0 (2013-12-25) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
[2014-01-16 09:26:55] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=34168 port=4000
Auto-regenerating enabled: source -> public
[2014-01-16 09:26:55] regeneration: 94 files changed
>>> Change detected at 09:26:57 to: screen.scss
identical public/stylesheets/screen.css 

Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects,
FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will
be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please
let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b
- Travis Tilley
```

It seems like everything should be working, but it previews a blank page at the localhost.
Here is my repo on github: https://github.com/stecd/octopress I forked it from the original Octopress repo and then copied it to my directory.

I followed this blog to start using octopress: http://learnaholic.me/2012/10/10/deploying-octopress-to-github-pages-and-setting-custom-subdomain-cname/

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: check your public folder; if your generated files are in public/FolderName you'll need to use localhost:4000/FolderName to preview

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue, see https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/1395

The issue is marked as closed, though I am not sure because I have the same issue. A simple workaround is to use Chrome instead of Safari.

Answer (score 0):

rake generate

then

rake preview

Here is a post I wrote about rake commands on Octopress http://www.tomordonez.com/blog/2013/03/12/rake-commands-in-octopress-on-github/